# How to restore delta of Databse in case of rollback

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We are using PostgreSQL in AWS RDS service. We are planning upgrade of PostgreSQL major version from 12.11 to 14.7. We will take a manual snapshot before upgrade. Let's say we have to do a rollback after 7 or 24 hours, is there a way to extract the delta of the new changes that have gone into the upgraded RDS database at the time of rollback ?
Does anyone have any tool/suggestions on how to take care of this scenario ?